# Tensor product distributive property?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors

Is it true that for vectors $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ we have
$$|a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle \langle c| \otimes \langle d|= |a \rangle \langle c| \otimes |b \rangle \langle d|?$$
So does this kind of distributive law hold for tensor products?

Comment: That doesn't look like a distributive law (which is of the form $a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b+a\cdot c$ for some product $\cdot$ and some addition $+$) to me, and furthermore, this doesn't look like a physics question to me (the properties of the tensor product are purely linear-algebraic in nature, there is no physics component to it).

Comment: The left side and the right side don't even appear to live in the same space.

Comment: It's confusing at first site because it is an operator equation; but both sides  are operators on the same tensor product space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are situations where a rule like this applies: tensor product of two functions applied to the tensor product of two vectors; this yields the tensor product of the first function to the first vector with the result of the second function applied to the second vector.

Here it appears that you have the tensor product of two kets, $|a>|b>=|ab>$, multiplied by the tensor product of the two bras, $<c|<d|=<cd|$. Their product as an operator, the outer product |a$b><cd|$.

So is $|ab><cd| =|a><c|⊗|b><d|$? We can test this by applying it to the product ket $|xy>=|x>|y>=|x>⊗|y>$.   When you do this you will find that they give the same result:  $<c|x><d|y>|ab>$.

So the answer is yes, they are equivalent.

But no, it is not a distributive law; instead it is simply the tensor space at work: it keeps the functions & vectors nicely separated while simultaneously keeping them in the correct order.  This is why, if you preserve the order, as I have done in the alternative notations, you can drop the tensor product operator symbol, $⊗$, without fear of making any mistakes ... just as we drop the ordinary multiplication symbol in algebra.  It's all a matter of getting used to the concepts along with the notation.

Comment: Modified slightly to show the tensor algebra correctly.